# An Eastern Jackpot

Tags: riddle, board-games

> Normally I'm for 9
>
> Exceptionally I'm for 13
>
> To east, I am from heaven
>
> To other directions, I am from earth
>
> The brightest primary color
>
> You either care about 1 and 9
>
> Or entirely forget about numbers
>
> Now wind blows from every direction
>
> Better conceal them all, then another me
>
> They blew 4 times? Then yet another me
>
> But if you can't afford that, call the Bulgarian dragons!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is referring to a

> limit hand in many Mahjong styles, maybe more specifically the yakuman hands in Riichi?

namely

Normally I'm for 9

> Nine Gates, a "normal" hand in shape

Exceptionally I'm for 13

> Thirteen Orphans; an irregular or exceptional hand

To east, I am from heaven

> the Heavenly Hand

To other directions, I am from earth

> and the Earthly Hand

The brightest primary color

> All Green

You either care about 1 and 9

> All Terminals

Or entirely forget about numbers

> All Honors

Now wind blows from every direction

> (Big/Small) Four Winds

Better conceal them all, then another me

> Four Concealed Triplets

They blew 4 times? Then yet another me

> I can't place this one other than being another Four Winds - Four Quads, maybe?

But if you can't afford that, call the Bulgarian dragons!

> Three Big Dragons

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Points in Mahjong (Hong Kong rules)?

Normally I'm for 9

> Commonly you score points for three sets of three (e.g., if the sets are all from the same suit).

Exceptionally I'm for 13

> Sometimes you get points for special hands of 13 (e.g., "Thirteen Orphans"/"Thirteen Wonders")

To east, I am from heaven

> The East player gets extra points from a "Heavenly Hand" (winning with the initial hand)

To other directions, I am from earth

> Players in other directions get extra points from an "Earthly Hand" (winning right when East discards their first tile)

The brightest primary color

> Not sure about this one, I suppose you get a point for having a set of red dragons.

You either care about 1 and 9

> A hand with only 1's and 9's ("Orphans") gives you extra points.

Or entirely forget about numbers

> A hand with no numbered tiles (all honor tiles) gives you extra points.

Now wind blows from every direction

> Mahjong has wind tiles for North/East/West/South, and you get a point for having a set of wind tiles (either for the prevailing wind or your own wind).

Better conceal them all, then another me

> You get extra points for having all your tiles concealed when you win.

They blew 4 times? Then yet another me

> Could be either: (a) you can get an extra point if you draw the 4th tile for a set of winds you have or (b) you get extra points for having sets of all four winds.

But if you can't afford that, call the Bulgarian dragons!

> You get an extra point for a set of white, red, or green "dragons" (credit to El-Guest for pointing out the relation to the colors of the Bulgarian flag).

Comment: Hint: Bulgarian colours are white, green, and red — what might be special about white dragons, green dragons, and red dragons in the answer you’ve noted? (For the record, I think you’re 100% correct)

Comment: rot13Lrnu, znuwbat vf pbeerpg. Abj cyrnfr vairfgvtngr ubj gb cynl znuwbat!) :)